# How can I display the name of my admin full name after login - Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

I am having a trouble on displaying my admin's full name, like for example admin full name is John Doe, it is not displaying. I am still learning codeigniter please give me advice thank you!

here is my controller

```
            //Get username
        $username = $this->input->post('username');

        //Get and encrypt the password
        $password = $this->input->post('password');

        // Login user
        $user_id = $this->role_model->login($username, $password);


        if ($user_id) {
        // Create session
        $user_data = array(
            'user_id' => $user_id,
            'name' => $user_id->name,
            'username' => $username,
            'logged_in' => true
        );

        $this->session->set_userdata($user_data);

        //Set message
        $this->session->set_flashdata('user_loggedin','You are now logged in');

        redirect('pages/index');
```

here is my View - where I would like to display my full name, as you can see ***'name'*** is the data field I have to display but it is does not show anything, it gives an error that says name is not defined.

```
  <li><a> Welcome, <?php echo $this->session->name ?> </a></li>
```

Model

```
        public function login($username, $password){
        //Validate
        $this->db->where('username',$username);
        $this->db->where('password',$password);

        $result = $this->db->get('users');

        if ($result->num_rows() == 1) {
            return $result->row(0)->id;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Most likely the problem is not in view. Check `$user_id` and `$user_id->name` after `$this->role_model->login`. Add to the application log, for example.

Comment: @ElenaVasilenko , please check my model. thank you, I think I'm missing something in the model :(

Comment: @ElenaVasilenko do you have any solution mam?

Comment: See my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your method `login()` returns only id = digit (`return $result->row(0)->id;`), not object (in controller your get `$user_id->name`).

Do this, in the model:

```
if ($result->num_rows() == 1) {
    return $result->row(0); // fix
}else{
    return false;
}
```

In the controller:

```
$user = $this->role_model->login($username, $password);

$user_data = array(
    'user_id' => $user->id, // fix
    'name' => $user->name, // fix
    'username' => $username,
    'logged_in' => true
);
```

Comment: wow :) can you please explain to me why the model is the problem? :( i thought my logic worked well, but your solution worked better. problem solved.

Comment: @codeislife For the variable `$user_id` to be an object (your try get object property `$user_id->name`), the `login()` method must return an object (`return $result->row(0);`). But it returned scalar value (`return $result->row(0)->id;`).

Answer (score 0):

It shows undefined because it is indeed undefined.
In your view your're trying to echo the returning value of a function called `userdata()`, does that function actually exist? Or is `$this->session->userdata` an array? in which that case, you need to use `[ index ]` to acces a member within an array. i.e. `$this->session->userdata['name']`, but also, that member needs to exist first.

Comment: hello kindly see my edited question , I've edited it and add the name, and put it as a value, but still did not show the name

Comment: Solls, as you can see I need to display the name of the logged in user.

Comment: hello sir, do you know how can we solve this? I can't put static value to the name :(

Comment: According to the official docs https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html, you would need to write $this->session->userdata('name');

Answer (score 0):

```
     controller   : 

     if($this->Login_model->login_valid($email,$password))
        {
            $sessiondata = array(
                'username' => $email
            );
            $this->session->set_userdata('logged_in', $sessiondata);
            redirect('narson');     
        }
        else
        {
            $this->session->set_flashdata('error',"Invalid Username And password");
            redirect('login');
        }


       model:

     public function login_valid($username,$password)
     {
        $this->db->where('username',$username);
        $this->db->where('password',$password);
        $query = $this->db->get('admin');

       if($query->num_rows() > 0)
      {
       return true;
      }
      else
      {
      return false;
      }
    }
```

Comment: kindly see my edited question, still the problem exists.

Comment: you first print $user_id and check name available or not

Comment: if ($result->num_rows() == 1) {
            return $result->row[0]->id;
        }else{
            return false;
        }